# Access Query - Returning Non-duplicated and Specific Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running into walls at the moment trying to write statements that would return specific records in a table that may have some duplicated unique value (Employee ID). Please see below for example: (The table below was imported using a saved import and all fields are in ShortText data type and there's no PK or indexes setup when imported)

| EMPID | ActNumber | Status | ReqDate | LastDateChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 185236 | Closed | 02/01/2019 | 01/01/2020 |
| 123 | 210390 | Open | 01/01/2020 |  |
| 123 | 312395 | Closed | 01/01/2020 |  |
| 432 | 832102 | Open | 06/01/2020 |  |
| 313 | 921235 | Closed | 03/03/2020 | 05/01/2020 |
| 313 | 952305 | Closed | 03/03/2020 |  |
| 610 | 182349 | Closed | 11/01/2018 |  |

The requirement would be to create a report that returns the records using the following criteria in order:

1. Max(CDate([ReqDate]))
2. [Status]
3. If duplicate EMPID records found then take Open [Status]
4. If duplicate EMPID records found but only Closed [Status] then return the one where [LastDateChange] is not null

The only way I can think of doing this is through multiple statements:

- One to return the Max [ReqDate] with [Status] Open
- One to return the Max [ReqDate] with another statement looking at the duplicates with Closed [Status] And [LastDateChange] is not null
- Create a temp table that would take in the records from the above queries before adding to the final table

That's the logic I was thinking of doing, but so far stuck on building it (feel like it's too windy). The final result that I'm looking for would be the following output -

| EMPID | ActNumber | Status | ReqDate | LastDateChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 210390 | Open | 01/01/2020 |  |
| 432 | 832102 | Open | 06/01/2020 |  |
| 313 | 921235 | Closed | 03/03/2020 | 05/01/2020 |
| 610 | 182349 | Closed | 11/01/2018 |  |

Any help would be wonderful and greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION and NOT IN returns desired output for given sample data.

```
SELECT EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange FROM tblTest 
    WHERE Status = "Open"
UNION SELECT EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange FROM tblTest 
    WHERE NOT LastDateChange Is Null 
    AND EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM tblTest WHERE Status="Open")
UNION SELECT EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange FROM tblTest 
    WHERE LastDateChange Is Null 
    AND EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM tblTest WHERE Status="Open") 
        AND EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM tblTest WHERE NOT LastDateChange Is Null 
        AND EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM tblTest WHERE Status="Open"))
;
```

Updated - KNog
This is a revised of the above suggestion and I got the correct output.

```
SELECT tblTest.EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange 
FROM tblTest 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT EmpID, Max(CDate(ReqDate)) As MaxDate From tblTest WHERE Not EmpID Is Null AND Status = 'Open' GROUP BY EmpID) As MaxOpnAct
ON tblTest.EmpID = MaxOpnAct.EmpID
WHERE Status = "Open"

UNION SELECT tblTest.EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange 
FROM tblTest
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT EmpID, Max(CDate(ReqDate)) As MaxDate From tblTest WHERE Not EmpID Is Null AND Status = 'Closed' GROUP BY EmpID HAVING Count(EmpID)=1) As MaxClsNonDup
ON tblTest.EmpID = MaxClsNonDup.EmpID

UNION SELECT tblTest.EmpID, ActNumber, Status, ReqDate, LastDateChange 
FROM tblTest
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT EmpID, Max(CDate(ReqDate)) As MaxDate From tblTest WHERE Not EmpID Is Null AND Status = 'Closed' GROUP BY EmpID HAVING Count(EmpID)>1) As MaxClsDup
ON tblTest.EmpID = MaxClsDup.EmpID
WHERE NOT LastDateChange Is Null
     AND Status = 'Closed'
     AND CDate(ReqDate) = MaxDate
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked a lot better. However, it didn't output the ones that a 'Closed' no duplicate and ones that are duplicate with 'Closed' which then filtered using the Not LastDateChange Is Null. That is probably my fault for the unclear requirements. However, this is great as start out for me, thank you! I've also re-wrote my steps below which is much more condense and of course I can also include UNION between the 3 queries as well.

Comment: When I implemented the above method into my actual project, I noticed I was getting duplicated records in return since the UNION joined all records together regardless if the previous query result already has the same matching EMPID or not. So what I did to get around was instead of utilizing the UNION, I just (in my case) create the table with the first set of queries, then insert the next one into the newly created table while omitting out the EMPID where it matches in the table. This is then done the same for the last one, yielding the final output that I was expected.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution though I'm sure that this can be simplified further to get the same end result. Below is what I came up with using 3 steps (these are probably resource-hogging and time-consuming, especially on a table that has over 60k records):

1. Extract records with latest date AND status open regardless if duplicate or not (if the account is open with the same request date as another account that is closed, the open one is selected).
2. Extract records that are closed AND are not duplicate.
3. Extract records that have duplicates with status closed AND select those with the last change date where it's not null/empty.

After that aggregate everything together into the target table.

Sorry, I tested this with another table I made on my work computer for testing, but it's pretty much the same.

This is the first part (Add Open accounts only):

```
SELECT tblTest.[EMPID], tblTest.[AccountNumber], tblTest.[Status], tblTest.[RequestDate], tblTest.[RequestDate] AS RequestDate2    
INTO tblTestOutput    
FROM tblTest    
INNER JOIN (    
SELECT qryFullColumns.[EMPID],    
qryFullColumns.[AccountNumber],    
qryFullColumns.[Status],    
qryFullColumns.[RequestDate],    
qryFullColumns.[LastRequestDate]    
FROM (    
SELECT IIf(Isnull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) AS EMPID,    
tblTest.[AccountNumber],    
tblTest.[Status],    
IIf(Not tblTest.[RequestDate] Is Null, tblTest.[RequestDate],'12/31/2999') AS RequestDate,    
tblTest.[LastRequestDate]    
FROM tblTest)  AS qryFullColumns    
INNER JOIN (    
SELECT qryMaxReqDate.EMPID,    
Max(CDate(qryMaxReqDate.MaxReqDate)) AS MaxReqDate    
FROM (    
SELECT IIf(Isnull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) AS EMPID,    
IIf(Not [RequestDate] Is Null,[RequestDate],'12/31/2999') AS MaxReqDate    
FROM tblTest    
)  AS qryMaxReqDate    
GROUP BY EMPID)  AS qryMaxReqDate    
ON qryFullColumns.[EMPID] = qryMaxReqDate.[EMPID]    
WHERE CDate(qryFullColumns.[RequestDate]) = qryMaxReqDate.[MaxReqDate]    
)  AS qryMaxReqDate    
ON IIf(IsNull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) = qryMaxReqDate.[EMPID]    
WHERE qryFulLColumns.[Status] = 'Open' AND tblTest.[Status] <> 'Closed';
```

For the second step to add only non-duplicate records with closed status:

```
INSERT INTO tblTestOutput ([EMPID], [AccountNumber], [Status], [RequestDate], [RequestDate2])    
SELECT tblTest.[EMPID], tblTest.[AccountNumber], tblTest.[Status], tblTest.[RequestDate], tblTest.[RequestDate] as [RequestDate2]    
FROM tblTest    
INNER JOIN (    
SELECT qryMaxReqDate.EMPID, Max(CDate(qryMaxReqDate.MaxReqDate)) AS MaxReqDate    
FROM (    
SELECT IIf(Isnull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) As EMPID,    
IIf(Not [RequestDate] Is Null,[RequestDate],'12/31/2999') As MaxReqDate    
FROM tblTest    
) As qryMaxReqDate    
GROUP BY EMPID HAVING Count([EMPID]) =1    
) As qrySub ON IIf(IsNull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) = qrySub.[EMPID]    
WHERE tblTest.[Status] = 'Closed'
```

And the last step is to add the duplicate accounts that are closed with the last request date:

```
SELECT tblTest.[EMPID], tblTest.[AccountNumber], tblTest.[Status], tblTest.[RequestDate], tblTest.[RequestDate] as [RequestDate2]    
FROM tblTest    
INNER JOIN (    
SELECT qryMaxReqDate.EMPID, Max(CDate(qryMaxReqDate.MaxReqDate)) AS MaxReqDate    
FROM (    
SELECT IIf(Isnull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) As EMPID,    
IIf(Not [RequestDate] Is Null,[RequestDate],'12/31/2999') As MaxReqDate    
FROM tblTest) As qryMaxReqDate    
GROUP BY EMPID HAVING Count([EMPID]) >1    
) As qrySub ON IIf(IsNull(tblTest.[EMPID]), 'ACT' & Right(tblTest.[AccountNumber],6), tblTest.[EMPID]) = qrySub.[EMPID]    
WHERE tblTest.[Status] = 'Closed' AND Not tblTest.[LastRequestDate] Is Null
```